# In Rails how to set two sets of routes to one resource? (Example Category for Photos and Albums)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `Categories` model which is shared by the both Albums and Photos. I need to use Photo Categories under `/photos/categories` and Album Categories under `/albums/categories`. How can I do this?

I tried to do it but failed. First I set the routes like this :

```
namespace :albums do
    resources :categories
end

namespace :photos do
    resources :categories, controller: 'photos/categories'
end
```

Then in the view I printed the category links like this :

```
link_to category.name.titleize, photos_category_path(category)
```

The links are fine but when I visit them I get this error :

```
uninitialized constant Photos
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: what is the name of your controller? do you have controllers in inner directory?

Comment: @TheShalit The controller is Photos and the other one Albums. Also have a one named Categories. No inner controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both `categories` controllers need to be defined in their own namespace:

```
# controllers/albums/categories_controller.rb
module Albums
  class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end

# controllers/photos/categories_controller.rb
module Photos
  class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I had to remove the `controller: 'photos/categories'` part from the route and also add `< ApplicationController` to the two classes :-)